# Is the capacity required to be preserved when moving a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, language-lawyer, move-semantics

Consider the following code:

```
std::vector vec;
vec.reserve(500);
size_t cap = vec.capacity();

std::vector newVec = std::move(vec);
assert(cap == newVec.capacity());
```

In pretty much any implementation you run across, this will work. I don't care about what implementations do. I want to know what the standard *requires*. Will the moved-to `vector` have the same capacity as the original? Or will the assert trigger?

Comment: If the capacity were to change, that would completely break the motivation for having move semantics in the first place, which is to avoid unnecessary copying and reallocation. I don't have the standard at hand, though, so I can't give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the standard, it appears that nothing is required from the move constructor, however as @amaurea says, it would completely defeat the purpose of move semantics if the move constructor were to try and allocate or deallocate memory, so I would expect the capacity to remain the same in all implementations.

---

**23.2.1 General container requirements**

*Expression*

```
X u(a);
X u = a;
```

*Assertion/note pre-/post-condition*

Requires: `T` is CopyInsertable into X (see below).
post: `u == a`

---

The standard only requires that `newVec == vec`. As capacity is not taken into consideration for `std::vector::operator==`, `newVec` need not necessarily have the same capacity as `vec`.

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer contradicts your warning in the last paragraph, so it's hard to tell which assertion you're making more strongly.

Answer (score 9):

C++11 standard requirements on move constructor for `std::vector` are (Table 99 — Allocator-aware container requirements):

```
X(rv)
X u(rv)
```

- move construction of allocator shall not exit via an exception
- post: u shall have the same elements as `rv` had before this construction; the value of `get_allocator()` shall be the same as the value of `rv.get_allocator()` before this construction.
- complexity: constant

Here is no requirements/guarantee on capacity. But we can make conclusion that constant complexity implicitly denies any reallocations. And I cannot see any other *logical* reason to change capacity except reallocation. So it shall be the same.

From the other point of view if the moved-from vector is empty, it is perfectly legal to just ignore it and default-construct itself. This would still be O(1), as it doesn't require any per-element constructs. (Thanks to [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) for this issue).

Also implemenation possibly could shrink capacity to the size using `hint` parameter of `std::allocator::allocate` function:

```
pointer allocate(size_type, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0);
```

The use of `hint` is unspecified, but intended as an aid to locality if an implementation so desires. So some sofisticated solution possibly could pass vector storage pointer as `hint` and use `realloc` on it to shrink capacity.

**Conclusion:** looks like standard doesn't guarantee capacity preserving on moving `std::vector`, storage potentially could be shrinked.

Comment: "*But we can make conclusion that constant complexity implicitly denies any reallocations.*" +1

Comment: Seems like an implementation could just reduce the capacity to the size and still satisfy all the legal requirements, though it would be a pointless waste.

Comment: I could see a reasonable implementation doing a `realloc` to shrink the `vector` down so that `size() == capacity()`. Constant complexity does not preclude this.

Comment: @PeterAlexander : How could `std::allocator<>` make use of `realloc` with its current interface?

Comment: @ildjarn: In theory, a template specialization which happens to know that its allocator used `malloc` internally could just call `realloc` on the pointer.

Comment: @ildjarn: It doesn't have to. There's a high level rule in the standard that allows the implementation to do any optimisation it sees fit as long as the observable behaviour is the same. Also, what aschepler said :-P

Comment: @aschepler: But what part of the `std::allocator<>` interface could use `realloc` under the covers?

Comment: But initially, I was thinking of a weird implementation that didn't even do any `realloc` or similar: just change the vector capacity for no good reason.  The memory is still allocated, but it won't ever be used.

Comment: A very clever implementation could even do optimisations on the whole vector and allocate everything on the stack (if the situation allows). I don't think there's anything that disallows that in certain situations.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: That's known as Small Buffer Optimization, and Dinkumware/Microsoft's `std::string` does it.

Comment: @PeterAlexander : You're saying that `std::allocator<T>` can do that? The standard requires that the default allocator for `std::vector<T>` is `std::allocator<T>`, no specializations, no customization...

Comment: @Rost: The concern here is that, since `vec` is empty, it is perfectly legal for `newVec` to just ignore the empty moved-from object and default-construct itself. This would still be O(1), as it doesn't require any per-element constructs.

Comment: @MooingDuck Don't think such trick is applicable here, how can you move automatic storage object in constant time? You have to move it by elements which is linear or at least amortized const complexity.

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm repeating myself here, but the implementation can do *whatever it wants* as long as the observable behaviour is the same.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Good point, looks like it's not denied by standard.

Comment: @PeterAlexander : Allocating on the stack would _not_ have the same observable behavior.

Comment: @Rost: Moving automatic storage is _always_ constant time, since it has a small fixed upper limit.  Ildjarn is correct that this doesn't apply to `vector`s that contain non-POD types.  `string` does this because it requires the contained type to be POD.

Comment: @PeterAlexander Stack and other dirty tricks aren't applicable here, default allocator is required to use `::operator new(std::size_t)`

Comment: @Mooing Duck Really? What about moving/swapping `std::array`? It's not constant but linear time.

Comment: @Rost: You're right, I hadn't considered types whos stack size depends on `N`.  Tuples have the same issue.

Comment: @Rost: I'll repeat for the third time: implementation can do **whatever it wants** as long as the observable behaviour is the same.

Comment: @Peter Alexander Ooh, finally I see it. But, wait! Allocating on stack and via `::operator new(size_t)` is not the same observable behavior!

Comment: @Rost: The observable behaviour of `new` is just that it creates an object. As far as the standard is concerned, there is no stack or heap or `malloc`.