# Is std::vector::data() preserved by moving?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, language-lawyer, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does moving a vector invalidate iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021764/does-moving-a-vector-invalidate-iterators)

Consider the following codes:

```
std::vector<T> prepare(T*& data) {
    std::vector<T> buffer;
    // Fill in buffer.
    data = buffer.data();
    return buffer;
}

...

T* data;
auto vec = prepare(data);
// line 12
```

Is it possible that `vec.data() != data` in line 12? Similarly,

```
std::vector<T> buffer;
// ... Fill in buffer ...
T* data = buffer.data();
auto vec = std::move(buffer);
// line 5
```

Is it possible that `vec.data() != data` in line 5?

Practically both are not possible in the implementation of libstdc++ and libc++, because the move constructors are implemented as simple pointer assignments, but it seems the standard does not specify anything on it (similar to [Is the capacity required to be preserved when moving a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129219/is-the-capacity-required-to-be-preserved-when-moving-a-stdvector)). Can the "constant complexity" guarantee that `vec.data() == data`?

Comment: Things that invalidate iterators/pointers are pretty well enumerated.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124989/does-stdvectorswap-invalidate-iterators

Answer (score 0):

Constant complexity means the container isn't allowed to copy/move individual elements, so it must transfer ownership of the existing storage to the new object, so the pointer returned by `data()` must be the same.

For move assignment (rather than move construction) that is only true if `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is true for the vector's allocator type or the allocators compare equal.

Comment: Some crazy implementation could move/copy constant number of individual elements.

Comment: @zch: That's forbidden by the contiguity requirement.

Comment: @BenVoigt, what about `if(<10) copyAll(); else moveOwnership();`?

Comment: @zch: Check the two questions I linked in comments on this question.

Comment: @zch, that's known as the _small object optimization_ but `vector::swap()` must be nothrow, which disallows the small object optimization